# orderby is not working .showing error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in [null])

Tags: angular, pipe

My Angular 2 application has a table and its contents has to be sorted when I click the heading. Below is my code:

```
static _orderByComparator(a: any, b: any): number {

    if ((isNaN(parseFloat(a)) || !isFinite(a)) || (isNaN(parseFloat(b)) || !isFinite(b))) {
        //Isn't a number so lowercase the string to properly compare
        if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    }
    else {
        //Parse strings as numbers to compare properly
        if (parseFloat(a) < parseFloat(b)) return -1;
        if (parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b)) return 1;
    }

    return 0; //equal each other
}

transform(input: any, [config = '+']): any {

    if (!Array.isArray(input)) return input;

    if (!Array.isArray(config) || (Array.isArray(config) && config.length == 1)) {
        var propertyToCheck: string = !Array.isArray(config) ? config : config[0];
        var desc = propertyToCheck.substr(0, 1) == '-';

        //Basic array
        if (!propertyToCheck || propertyToCheck == '-' || propertyToCheck == '+') {
            return !desc ? input.sort() : input.sort().reverse();
        }
        else {
            var property: string = propertyToCheck.substr(0, 1) == '+' || propertyToCheck.substr(0, 1) == '-'
                ? propertyToCheck.substr(1)
                : propertyToCheck;

            return input.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
                return !desc
                    ? OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property])
                    : -OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property]);
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        //Loop over property of the array in order and sort
        return input.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
            for (var i: number = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
                var desc = config[i].substr(0, 1) == '-';
                var property = config[i].substr(0, 1) == '+' || config[i].substr(0, 1) == '-'
                    ? config[i].substr(1)
                    : config[i];

                var comparison = !desc
                    ? OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property])
                    : -OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property]);

                //Don't return 0 yet in case of needing to sort by next property
                if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
            }

            return 0; //equal each other
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I created a function for changing the order by value:

```
fororderbyfn(sortparam: any) {

    this.fororderby = (this.fororderby == sortparam) ? "-" + sortparam : sortparam;      


}
```

and this is my html code:

```
  <th>
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" 
       (click)="fororderbyfn('TICKET_NUMBER')">Ticket#
      <span [hidden]="!reverseSort">
        <img src="Style/images/sortup.png" />
      </span>
      <span [hidden]="reverseSort">
        <img src="Style/images/sortdown.png" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </th>
```

```
<tr *ngFor="#Tkt of ticketListData | orderBy : fororderby ">
```

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable

Comment: What Angular2 version?

Comment: angular 2 latest beta version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours `a` and `b` variables are probably not strings. Had the same problem and solved it by casting to string:

```
if (a + ''.toLowerCase() < b + ''.toLowerCase()) {
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: it is not sorting correctly..it is sorting the capital letters first and then the small letters..

Comment: whenever iam giving this.fororderby="" ,it is ascending the capital letters first and then the small letters..